# Constrain chess moves to board width with xskak and chessboard

Tags: chessboard, xskak

I'm using xskak and chessboard to typeset a game.  How can I constrain the printing of the moves to the with of the board?  I'm basically looking to constrain the width of the text box.  In the image below you can see that the moves extend both left and right of the area over the board.
[image]

Here is the MWE for this game:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}\\
\chessboard[label=False]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can just put the movements into a `\parbox` of the desired width:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\newchessgame
\parbox{60mm}{
\mainline{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e6
7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}
}

\chessboard[label=False]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
In light of the comments below, perhaps you want to use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

  \newchessgame
  \hspace*{7mm}\mainline{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6}\\
  \hspace*{7mm}\mainline{5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e6 7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9.  g5}
  \par\leavevmode\vspace*{-60mm}
  \chessboard[label=False]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Note that I have removed the use of [preview](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/preview) and used two `\mainline` commands to control the line spacing.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to offset the position of the parbox so that the left side of the text is flush with the left side of the board?  Or the parbox is centered over the board?

Comment: When in doubt try a random LaTeX command! For example, try putting `\hspace*{6mm}` before the `\parbox` command. Is there a reason why you are using the [preview](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/preview) package? I've not seen it before and would not have guessed that you needed it.

Comment: I am using preview because the code didn't seem to work without it (I get no pages of output written).  Do you know what preview actually does, I copied it from an example?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the \hspace*, I'm new enough at LaTeX that I don't know which random commands to try.

Comment: Do you know how to make the text box line break only right before a move number?  Do you know how to reduce the vertical space between the text and the diagram?  Or should I accept this answer now and ask these as separate questions?

Comment: The use of preview seems unnecessary. You can break the moves where ever you want -- see my edit. I can't work out how to remove the space between the moves and the chess board, so perhaps you need to ask another question to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  What is the role of the \\ between your mainline commands?

Comment: `\\ ` is roughly the same as `\newline`